# can I know how long time e.g addition insturction take in vhdl code result<a+b ;?

Tags: vhdl

how can I  know addition instruction or subtraction e.g result<= a+b ; how long time it takes in vhdl?
I am trying to measure the instruction time for ALU , each instruction addition , multiplication and other ALU instructions, please can any one help me? I used now time but it doesn't change the answer it always be the same for all operations

Comment: It depends on the synthesized logic and the device it is synthesised for. Not really VHDL related.

Comment: If you have a clock cohesive model you can use two assert statements to report the start of an instruction and when it's finished executing. The difference in simulation time between the two assertion events would be the execution time.  From your last statement it would appear there's knowledge of your design model required o answer better.  If the value of `now` is unchanged either you're measuring wrong or your model is pure behavioral.

Comment: yes my design is behavioral , I used case and when statement to select the choice and then calculate the result

Answer (score 1):

If you run synthesis on your design (top level) or on some sub parts you will get a rough estimation for the maximum frequency. The tools use a coarse model of logic levels, fan-outs, worst-case propagation delays and mean wire delays. This is just a hint. For real values you need to run a complete timing analysis on the fully placed and routed design and you need to assign timing constraints.

The language itself has no feature for your question. It's possible to use a detailed simulation model -- as David described -- and 'measure' the propagation delays. But this is no replacement for a static timing analysis (STA).